# HTTP BODY in memory rather than writing to disk

Tags: c, http, libcurl

Is it possible to have the body of an HTTP request stored in memory as a stream of data.

Specifically, I am using the libcurl C library to write a few HTTP requests and the idea is to have the body of the HTTP responses in memory rather than writing to disk.

The various curl_easy_setopt options (CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA) actually write the body of the response to a file. What I want is to be able to work on the data stream that is in the body directly, irrespective of what it is.

Something to the tune of:

```
char* dataStream = HTTP_RESPONSE_BODY
```

This is because the HTTP body will be passed on to something else for further processing and writing to disk and reading back will take time, particularly for large files. I know I may not have sufficient memory to hold large data but it is definitely going to be faster than writing to disk and reading again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell cURL to pass data to a function defined by your own by making it matching the prototype: `size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);` and call: `curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);`

This is mentioned in the official libcurl tutorial at: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html